# YouTube API V3 - HTTP referrer restriction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, fetch-api

I'm using the YouTube V3 API for my application, and I seem to be missing something now that I'm restricting the key to websites that I list. When the key is completely unrestricted, the app works, but I don't want everyone and their mom using my key for their sites (my code is on GitHub - this is a vanilla JavaScript app so I cannot hide my key). Here is my fetch call...

```
fetch(baseURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => displayYoutubeResults(responseJson))
    .catch(err => alert("YouTube's API is acting up again. Site Administrator is dealing with it.", err));
```

The baseURL is simply the URL making the fetch call. Is some type of Header required now that I have restrictions on the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app produces a JSON error response like the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

then it means that, indeed, you have to pass to the API endpoint you're calling a HTTP `Referrer` header as:

```
fetch(baseURL, {
  referrer: "REFERRER"
})
```

where `REFERRER` is to be replaced with a value that matches one of the URL patterns you entered on Google's developers console upon selecting the checkbox `HTTP Referrers (web sites)` under the section `Application restrictions` and adding one or more URL pattern items under the subsection `Website restrictions`.

Nevertheless, bear in mind that using this kind of application restriction applied to your API key does not protect you from (quote) *everyone and their mom using your key for their sites*. This is so, since you say that your app's source code is public (implying that everyone could read easily a valid HTTP referrer from the source code itself).

---

If you set up an API key HTTP referrer restriction (as I mentioned above) to be the URL of your site (e.g. `http://www.foobar.com`), then using [`referrerPolicy`](https://javascript.info/fetch-api#referrer-referrerpolicy) as:

```
fetch(baseURL, {
  referrerPolicy: "origin"
})
```

you'll avoid having to specify the URL `http://www.foobar.com` in the source code itself.

However, the `referrerPolicy` option is not entirely secure either, since an interested third-party could still derive your URL if having at disposal additional information about your app.

Comment: I went with the "origin" route. This allows me to easily work with the app with my live server and not have to edit the code whenever pushing it to GitHub. Thank you for this!

Comment: I am having the same issue in a sveltekit app but doing both of the previous things does not seem to work for me...don't know what to do in my case to get it to work...it works fine without restriction...