# Youtube Data API HTTP Referrer Restriction not working with Sveltekit and Vercel

Tags: http, http-headers, youtube-data-api, vercel, sveltekit

There is a similar question on SO, and I have tried to do those things with my situation, but it is not working for me, hence asking this question as well.

[YouTube API V3 - HTTP referrer restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234818/youtube-api-v3-http-referrer-restriction)

I am building an app using the web framework Svelte/Kit and deploying to Vercel. I am trying to use the Youtube Data API to get videos from a playlist and show them in a player, all using an API from a Youtube channel I own. Without any API restrictions I am able to make it work just fine in development and production, but when adding an HTTP Referrer restriction in the Google Cloud Console I cannot get it to work in production, only in development, using localhost:5173. I cannot use IP Address restriction because sites hosted on Vercel do not always use the same IP Address in different regions, as I understand it. So the HTTP Referrer is my only choice for restriction at this point.

In any case, when adding the following website HTTP Referrer restriction:

```
https://lstv.vercel.app/*
```

...everything even works when I am developing locally using localhost...it's just not working in production...

In Sveltekit here is my API endpoint:

```js
import { YOUTUBE_API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export async function GET({ url }) {

  const page_token = url.searchParams.get('page_token');
  const playlist_id = url.searchParams.get('playlist_id');
  const maxResults = 10;

  const new_url =
  `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=${playlist_id}&key=${YOUTUBE_API_KEY}&part=snippet&maxResults=${maxResults}&pageToken=${page_token}`;

  const response = await fetch(new_url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      // 'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    // referrerPolicy: 'origin',
    referrer: 'https://lstv.vercel.app/*',
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data));
  // return json(data); // Sveltekit JSON helper, which is optional
}
```

...I have tried to use both `referrer` and `referrerPolicy` but `referrer` only works in development and `referrerPolicy` does not work at all.

..in my sveltekit page I call the api via this function:

```js
  async function fetchLatestVideos() {
    
    const response = await fetch(`/api/youtube/?playlist_id=${playlist_id}&page_token=${initial_page_token}`);

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(`Loaded Page Data: `, data);
      next_page_token = data.nextPageToken;
      videos = data.items;
      current_video_id = videos[0]?.snippet?.resourceId?.videoId;
      current_video_image = videos[0]?.snippet?.thumbnails?.maxres?.url;
      current_video_title = videos[0]?.snippet?.title;
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to fetch data:', response.statusText);
    }

  }
```

...which again, works in development but not in production...

In production I'm not sure how to get an error message to show up. I am currently getting a 500 for the api url, and a `failed to fetch data` message...but nothing else...

So I'm pretty stumped myself on how to make this work in production with the HTTP Referrer restrictions in place, which is a client requirement.

UPDATE:

Just learned that I can loop up logs in Vercel and found this:

```
Error: The 'referrer' field on 'RequestInitializerDict' is not implemented.
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/endpoints/api/youtube/_server.js:10:25)
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:222:25)
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2666:27)
```

...which is great...but I don't know what to change to make it work properly now...

...but at least it's something...

UPDATE 2:

I think I might have figured it out...need to test a few more things, however...will add more after I have a better understanding...